# 20% of X is Y, then X is?

Tags: percentages

Please help me to find out `X`:

20% of X is Y, then what is X?

For Example if 20% of `X` is 1030, what was that `X`?

Please don't just give me the fish. Let me know how to catch.

Thanks

Comment: $1030 = 20\%\cdot X - X = -80\%\cdot X$

Comment: You might have meant to say "Let me know *how* to catch." Otherwise, your fishing for people.

Comment: *you're* Apparently, I'm also having trouble with English.

Comment: @JimmyK4542, u right. I just edited :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay,

$1030=\dfrac{20}{100}x-x\implies 1030=-\dfrac{4}{5}x$

$x=-\dfrac{5150}{4}$